# Ubuntu - Unclear desktop - Missing horizontal pixels?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I just download Ubuntu 14.04 and created bootable USB with it.
On 2 PCs it is working realy great, both run with out install and preinstalled.
On both pc system auto loads 2 monitors, full hd - there is no problems.

But one pc, almost the same as previous 2 (gtx660ti, the same monitors DVI connected). System starts only on one monitor, and it's very unclear, pixelated. It seems like some horizontal pixels are missing.

I'm attaching bad photo (sorry I do not have better camera), and hope you can see and recognize problem.

http://1drv.ms/1JKHr6M

P.S. Windows working perfectly clear.

Edit:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 841f
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I checked 32bit to, but it's unclear too.
Also look, on this PC when Ubuntu is starting/closing it looks like:
http://1drv.ms/1MU9GTu
On other PC it's fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.